# how to log the operation of business object in an elegant way by using design pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

For example I have two class call Log,and Order,Order is a business object. If i need to log the insert operation of business object Order.Then i have to do something like that:

```
public class Order
{
  IOrderDal dal = DALFactory.DataAccess.CreateOrder();
  logger = new Logger();
  public void Inerst(OrderInfo order)
  {
    dal.Insert(order);
    logger.log(orderInfo.ToString(),"Insert",DateTime.Now.ToString());
  }
public class Logger
{
  public void log(string description,string operation,string time)
  {
    ....//dosometing to persist the information
  }
}
```

My question is that if i have hundreds of business object need to be logged,then i have to add the code like  `logger.log(orderInfo.ToString(),"Insert",DateTime.Now.ToString())` in each
operation of bussiness objects?I think there must be some desgin methodlogy to make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging is the canonical example of an application for [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and using AOP you will be able to achieve what you want. AOP frameworks allow you to declare methods which are applied to other methods at stages during the methods execution. This allows you to invoke some code before a method executes, after a method has finished executing, if a method throws an exception ect etc.

Usually you have access to the metadata about the method (its name, arguments etc) so you could easily log something like the method that is being executed and the parameters the method was called with.

In .net the largest and most popular framework for AOP is probably [Postsharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) and they have an example of [how logging with Postsharp works](https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging).

There are [plenty of other choices though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#cite_note-12).